# SQLAlchemy Date field less or equal query on empty value

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a problem querying records from MySql database with **SQLAlchemy**.
This is my table:

```
class CarLicenceData(Base):
    ...
    userIdOwner = sa.Column(sa.String(100))
    MOTExpiry = sa.Column(sa.Date)
    ...
```

And this is my query:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
car = session.query(CarLicenceData).filter(and_(
     CarLicenceData.MOTExpiry <= now.date(),
     CarLicenceData.MOTExpiry != None,
     CarLicenceData.userIdOwner == 'eu-west-1:97923fc8-2b0f-4caa-b6b9-7974941073ec'
)).one()
print car
<CarLicenceData(1585)>

car.MOTExpiry is None
True
```

It returns record even if MOTExpiry is None. What's wrong here?

Comment: I ran your code and it works absolutely fine on both mysql and postgresql.

Comment: Thats the point, interesting part is that other field with the same Date type works fine. I thought maybe migration mixed things up  but  no, on db level they are the same..

Comment: My point is, I cannot reproduce your issue. Which version of SQLAlchemy and mysql are you using? When I test with SQLAlchemy 1.2.5 and mysql 5.7, your code does not select rows with null MOTExpiry as you claim will happen.